# HTML - how to render unicode symbols appearing (from api) such as &#146; &#150; etc

Tags: html, unicode, encoding, character

There is a data quality issue in our app. Basically some characters from a very long time ago were not saved with standard chars.

Dashes appear as `&#150`;

Apostrophe appear as `&#146`;

etc

Is this standard Unicode? I have looked for a few tables but I couldn't find `&#150` or `&#146` that matches to the punctuation chars I'm expecting.

Also, is there an easy way to render those HTML characters? Right now, it is appearing as square boxes in some editors, and in Notepad++ it is appearing as SPA (in black box).

Comment: It looks like some private transliteration like [European Voynich Alphabet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_europeo_de_Voynich#EVA_extendido) where _controls_ like `&#146;` or `&#150;` are mapped to renderable glyphs. You need an associated font to render them as intended…

Comment: HTML entity `&#150;` is Unicode codepoint `U+0096 START OF GUARDED AREA`, which a browser may render as a dash. And HTML entity `&#146;` is Unicode codepoint `U+0092 PRIVATE USE TWO`, which a browser may render as an apostrophe.  It depends on the font used.